# Regex for replacing everything other than these matches?

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the following string:

```
https://87230a61de33450b964afbc0814884ec@p2238591.ingest.sentry.io/1504772008177343
```

*this is a dummy string, but chosen to replicate as accurately as possible the problem.

I have constructed the following RegEx:

```
/[^(\bhttps:\/\/\b)]|[^(\b\.ingest.sentry.io\/\b)]/g
```

With the idea that anything that is not the specific word `https://` or `.ingest.sentry.io/` is matched and removed.

However, my negation doesn't seem to be working:

[image]

What have I done wrong here?

I have also tried these variations:

```
[^(\bhttps:\/\/\b)|(\b\.ingest.sentry.io\/\b)]
```

```
[^(https:\/\/)]|[^(\.ingest.sentry.io\/)]
```

But to no luck ... just what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like a hexidecimal string; why not just make a regex to match that part of the URL and grab it? Unless I'm misreading, what's the eventual purpose for this regex? Stripping out everything except constant text will leave you with constant text.

Comment: That's not how `[^...]` works. `[^...]` is a character class, it matches a single character that isn't in the contents, not a string.

Comment: Ok so what should I use in it's place? I want to replace everything that isn't the "facets" of the DSN with a * to obfuscate it ...

Comment: @trincot Potential solution has not been found.

Comment: Oh I see you deleted your comment.

Comment: @Barmar I think you're incorrect, [^(https://)] would match everything other than "https://"

Comment: What do you mean, "think"? This is not a debate on belief, regular expressions are thoroughly documented and character classes (and character class negation) works exactly as it's documented they work.

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts rather, it will match _everything_ that doesn't contain a single character of `https://`. So it will just start matching individual characters in the string, rather than full stretches.

Comment: To exclude a whole string you need to use a negative lookahead or lookbehind.

Comment: @Blindy Please relax. I appreciate your contributions.

Comment: In PCRE you can [replace `\b(https:\/\/|\.ingest\.sentry\.io\/)\b(*SKIP)(*F)|.` with `*`](https://regex101.com/r/BXELct/1)

Answer (score 2):

**In PCRE** there are [verbs](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html) [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) available to skip something while matching.
Generally it works like this:   *stuff to be skipped (*SKIP)(*FAIL) | stuff to be matched*

```
(\bhttps:\/\/|\.ingest\.sentry\.io\/)(*SKIP)(*F)|.
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5gri5L/1) (was unsure about how you placed [`\b` word boundaries](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary))

---

**In Python** this works with [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) ([demo](https://tio.run/##LY6xCsIwGIT3PEXoYlNKkjZpE4WCkyAugmuWtkbtYBuSCBb67jFat/uP@/47M/vHNLIQhqeZrIdW3/Ubti4KABxs4ObhvXE7QqQoGW3r4qoZ4xXttjVvb11PZcGl5Lrfm7JkstoWeBjv2nns9OjtjIeJFBXlQpQ0ZoVgnG0AWHsaaBPVpWuFIoos6k@rPx7vSREUQ9nldDyjNDugBSeR/46zGrtXl/6e5TDJkhw6BIwdRh9Nh0L4AA)) or use a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and *callback*:

```
regex = r"(\bhttps:\/\/|\.ingest\.sentry\.io\/)|."
res = re.sub(regex, lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else "*", s)
```

[Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##Tc7NisIwFAXgfZ7i0o3tIPlpUhOFAR8km0avNWCbkERQ8N07ccbFLA@c794Tn@UaFrmufo4hFUhISIZv2FxLifnAmNG95ONOnFFKNXC336nx4k7cCGWMwtMx9r00w15Qv0yYC824lPSkPjAxcKV1z2tXa6nkhpCEEz7q@dS01v29sMyyl/1o@@E1B8u6F20qee9JSPPdtb9@C7dxducR5gPMdErhHlvRgb/8T3jLCM1Xs4XckZj8UirO3br@AA) or [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/XQYrh0/1) (using normal replace it will add extra `*`)

---

**In Javascript** using a callback and the same pattern with a capturing group:

```js
let s = 'https://87230a61de33450b964afbc0814884ec@p2238591.ingest.sentry.io/15047....'

let res = s.replace(/(\bhttps:\/\/|\.ingest\.sentry\.io\/)|./g, (m0,m1) => m1?m1:'*');
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you were told, that is not how you "negate" regular expressions. In fact, there is no negation of regular expressions in general, you have to write one that matches what you want to actually match. For example, it sounds like you want something like this:

```
^(?:https:\/\/)?(.*?)(?:\.ingest\.sentry\.io)(.*)$
```

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/tUjZjT/1